# A themeless but slightly devilish cryptic

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

[image]

#### ACROSS

**1** Grant F in T, perhaps (6)
**4** Bug (messed up): "Pride cometh after the summer" (6)
**9** Fez state: motorcoach tipped over, hat fell out (7)
**10** Essin' curves! (5)
**11** Primal-screamers have one day left for milder expressions of disappointment (4)
**12** Elementary, to CERN of Sixty-second Street (8)
**13** Vascular surgery replaces heparin: end of prank (6)
**15** Monet work showing a pair of socks (3-3)
**18** Frantic, at a combat zone, for a place beneath the surface of the earth in which to hide body (8)
**20** Yon tag: "and" (4)
**23** Area around St. Albans Cathedral sounds like organs (5)
**24** A sort of tray from a Chinese dynasty (postbellum) (7)
**25** Child preps for parties (6)
**26** Territory of mafia chief covering a Southeast Asia nation (6)

#### DOWN

**1** Sent one private message against a Koch (5)
**2** More from a patriarch with a biblical home, for one (7)
**3** Rap pet's real name is Tracy Lauren (4)
**5** Suggestion of egg being taken from saucepan, camouflaged: that's useful on Easter (7)
**6** Audience's demand for a divine sonneteer (5)
**7** 3D dish: it's root salad (7)
**8** Day in Faisalabad or Islamabad (5)
**13** Trivial coholonomy group: it may be useful in proving theorems in quantum gauge theory (7)
**14** Teeth Corp.'s gold, silver (8)
**16** Perhaps Catherine trains a mongrel (7)
**17** Cold-war radar system is puzzle for listeners (5)
**19** "Shake that heinie! Rock on!" —ballet principals (5)
**21** Sodium fume rises, becomes billions and billions of stars, man (5)
**22** A monster heads north for the specified reason (4)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Partial answer**

There are

> a couple of *printer's devilry* clues (maybe only one?), hence the "slightly devilish" in the title -- which I completely missed until others pointed it out to me in comments.

Almost-completed grid:

> [image]

and here are some explanations (more verbose than I usually give because the clues are harder and the definitions more cryptic than usual):

> 1a. To AFFORD is to grant (as in Johnson's "there is in London all that life can afford"). F in A FORD (model T).
>  4a. PRIDE* after S (for summer).
>  9a. MOROCCO is where the city of Fez is; (MOTORCOACH - HAT)*.
>  10a. &lit: ESSIN*, and sine curves are arguably S-like.
>  11a. "D'oh!"s. (S(-creamers) H(-ave) O(-ne) D(-ay))<.
>  12a. MINUTE+ST; to someone at CERN "elementary" would refer to elementary *particles* which are elementary because they can't be broken up into smaller things.
>  13a. AORTIC means pertaining to the aorta, a blood vessel; take ANTIC (prank) and replace N (HEPARIN end) with OR (operating room = surgery, in the sense of a place where surgery is done).
>  15a. Substring of "Monet work". Socks as in *punches*; thanks to jafe for pointing this out in comments.
>  18a. Substring of "Frantic at a combat [zone]".
>  20a. I guess this is a printer's devilry clue, but have so far been unable to solve it. (An earlier version of this answer guessed at EARS for amusing but unsurprisingly incorrect reasons.) But I'm not very confident it's p.d. for the following reason: after insertion it seems like the clue needs either to start with YONTAG or to end with AGAND; in the former case it seems like it has to be YON followed by a word beginning TAG, and there aren't many of those and I can't see any that makes a plausible sentence-beginning; in the latter case it seems like it has to end with the word AND, which is not a plausible sentence-ending. (Unless perhaps we are assuming some punctuation and taking it literally, as with my earlier attempt to suggest that double-quotes are "bunny EARS", but combining that with p.d. seems a bit much.) So, whichever way I slice it, I have trouble seeing how I can construct something that makes enough sense to be the filled-out version of a p.d. clue.
>  23a. St Alban's Cathedral is in St Albans in Hertfordshire, abbreviated HERTS, which sounds like HEARTS. (I confess I think the definition unfair.)
>  24a. A WARMING tray is WAR+MING.
>  25a. Several countries have a *political* party called LABOR. I had a poor guess at how the wordplay worked; in comments hexomino found a better explanation: LABOR in the sense of childbearing is, kinda, "child prep".
>  26a. [MA-I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ma-i) in DON; thanks to jafe for finding the former, of which I had never heard.
>  1d. AIMED = sent (definition seems a bit loose to me); a private message = AIM or A + IM; a Koch = Ed.
>  2d. FATHER with UR replacing A.
>  3d. The rapper Ice-T was born *Tracy Lauren* Marrow. This is a printer's devilry clue: "Rap pe[R ICE-]t's ...". Thanks to hexomino for spotting this.
>  5d. PASCUAN means pertaining to Easter *Island* and specifically is the name of a language used there; (SAUCEPAN-E(-gg))*.
>  6d. John DONNE wrote some (very fine) "Divine Sonnets" and his name sounds like DUN.
>  7d. "3D" here means 3 down, not 3-dimensional. ITSROOT*.
>  8d. Doris Day; substring.
>  13d. Substring of "trivial coholonomy" (cohomology and holonomy are things, but not coholonomy) ... and I think the "definition" here is a reference to a famous mnemonic for the digits of pi beginning "How I need a drink".
>  14d. INC  IS OR S. But the answer like the enumeration is 8 letters long and the space only 7; I assume INCISOR is wanted.
>  16d. Catherine the Great was a TSARINA; (STRAIN A)*.
>  17d. The Ballistic Missile Early Warning System's acronym sounds like BEMUSE.
>  19d. Initial letters of "That ... ballet".
>  21d. (NA GAS)<; Carl SAGAN was famous for talking about "billions and billions" of stars, miles, galaxies, etc.
>  22d. OGRE<. (Ergo = therefore = for the specified reason.)

Still missing:

> 20a, which I bet is a printer's devilry clue.

Credit where due:

> I submitted this with a lot of only-partially-understood wordplay, because I had to be AFK for a while; hexomino and jafe kindly figured out almost all of what I'd missed in comments below. Thanks also to OP for confirming and clarifying various things.

Comment: I think 1 across may actually be rot13(nssbeq, naq G pyhrf "N Sbeq" (Zbqry G))

Comment: And 25 across refers to "preparing for a kid" I think rather than homework.

Comment: 26a is probably [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ma-i)?

Comment: 15a is rot13(n cha jvgu "fbpx" zrnavat "chapu").

Comment: 1a, 15a, 26a are as @jafe said in the comments above. 20a is incorrect. 25a is as hexomino said in the comments above. 1d is the correct answer but the intended wordplay was rot13(frag, qrs; bar=n; vz=cevingr zrffntr; ntnvafg=arkg gb; n xbpu=rq). 3d is incomplete, as you noted. 5d is actually a language or script used there, so it's "useful". 13d's def was just supposed to be humorous, because it's a hard branch of physics. 14d was my error; sorry! The rest are correct. For some of what you missed, you may wish to check the puzzle's title.

Comment: 3 down rot13(vf cevagre'f qrivyel: Enccr**e vpr**-G'f erny anzr...)

Comment: Thanks, all! I would normally not have submitted something with so many gaps but I needed to be AFK for about an hour... I'll make appropriate edits. And, anyone else reading this, if you upvote my answer please also go and find something by hexomino and/or jafe and upvote that too!

Comment: 3d was intended as @hexomino said in the comments above.

Comment: OK, answer updated appropriately. Presumably 20a is like 3d, but I have so far completely failed to figure it out.

Comment: @msh210 You've accepted my answer even though I still have one clue unsolved. Surely that's a bit too generous?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan re your last comment: nah, it's close enough. :-)